# Need to verify if scikit-learn development version is installed correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been having trouble installing development version of scikitlearn. I am on windows 10 and I cloned the git repository and installed through

git clone https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git

python setup.py build_ext --inplace

at (base) C:\Users\YANG\scikit-learn> on anaconda
and when I ran pytest sklearn, I got

21 failed, 11679 passed, 74 skipped, 1 xfailed, 2472 warnings in 494.92 seconds

most of the fail was DocTestFailure and some Assertionerror

I am wondering if the scikit learn is properly installed or not as I see 21 fails.
and If so, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to use the anaconda environment and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. One of the developer left a message but I don't know what he is trying to say.

Here is the link to my issue report: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13560 
Thank you.